# Hitting EBS volume limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ebs

I am trying to launch 210 instances of type p2.xlarge. Earlier I am hitting instance limit which I have increased now to 300 but now I am getting  '**Client.VolumeLimitExceeded: Volume limit exceeded**' error. Can you please help to resolve this issue? Any one knows the

1. What is Volume limit?
2. What should I request to increase inorder to run 210 instance (p2.xlarge) and aviod this error.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/ebs_volume_limit_request/

Answer (score 1):

Your error means: `Client.VolumeLimitExceeded`: The limit on the number of EBS volumes or total storage was exceeded. Decrease usage or request an increase in your limits.

The AWS Limits page for EBS lists the default limit being 5,000 EBS volumes and 10,000 EBS snapshots. Total storage limit is 20 TB per type (gp2, io12, st1, sc1). **Make sure that this is not your issue.**

[Amazon Elastic Block Store (Amazon EBS) Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_ebs)

To request an increase for EBS go to [Volume List Increase Request](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/ebs_volume_limit_request/). On the same page your can change the `Limit Type` for other limit increases.

I would open a support case with Amazon support and ask them to review your requirements to make sure that all your limits are managed for this usage case instead of hitting one limit after the other. Amazon will definitely help you.

Comment: I am using General Purpose SSD (gp2) EBs of size 128 GiB according to that I have increased my volume storage limit to 40 TiB. Should I also need to increase IOPS?

Answer (score 0):

The default EBS limits are: [Amazon Elastic Block Store (Amazon EBS) Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_ebs)

It is the number of EBS volumes an account can use. You have a bigger problem if you are launching 210 `p2.xlarge` instances. You will hit various resource limits. You may need to request increase in limits for those resources.

- Delete unattached/unused EBS volumes in your account
- Check your EBS limits in: [Amazon EC2 Service Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html)
- Calculate the number of volumes you will be using for each instance (Check your AMI)
- Request for more EBS volume limit.

Comment: Is there any specific limit which I need to request Or any way to figure out which limit I am hitting. I mean Number of EBS volumes, volume storage or IOPS

Comment: @I'mAtishKumbhar As I mentioned, your request for large number of high powered instance is unusual. You will hit many resource limits. Without knowing anything about your AMI and your other requirements, it is difficult to comment. I would try to launch and create a support request when you hit a limit and try again until the instances are launched.

Comment: I am using General Purpose SSD (gp2)  EBs of size 128 GiB according to that I have increased my volume storage limit to 40 TiB. Should I also need to increase IOPS?